# Need help to extract the data of only one year from a .nc dataset in R

Tags: r, netcdf4

I need some help with a geospatial data project:

I downloaded this dataset of yearly mean temperatures: https://psl.noaa.gov/data/gridded/data.UDel_AirT_Precip.html ([this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay5Lw.png)) from which I need to data of 1990.

I imported the data into R with the following command:

> ras_tempdata_v5 = raster("PATH/air.mon.mean.v501.nc")

and was hoping I could go with something like

> tempdata_v5_90 <- raster(ras_tempdata_v5@history == 1990)

*(would the "raster" here be needed again or would it automatically be raster data?)*

to end up with just the data for 1990. But I have no idea where is the dataset the years are stored and how to access only the data for one specific year.

[This is what the dataset looks like in RSTudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFQ6G.png).

I also installed Panoply [(looked like this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzhx4.png) to find out something about the variable structure, but that didn't really help me either.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can accomplish what you are after by first calling the dataset as a RasterStack, which only reads a little bit of data about the rasters.  Then you can look at how the raster layers are named.  From there, you will use a regular expression to get the layer numbers for all layers representing 1990.  Then simply do a subset select of your rasterStack, and create a rasterBrick from your desired layers.  You can then remove the original rasterStack from you environment to save memory if you want.  Below is a reproducible example:

```
library(raster)

path<-"Path_to_your_rasters/air.mon.mean.v501.nc"
test<-stack(path)
lyrs<-names(test)
usethese<-grep(pattern="X1990",lyrs)#My machine reads each layer in with an "X", print lyrs to see if yours does the same.
MMAT<-brick(test[[usethese]])
rm(test)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot already, this worked pretty well so far. I didn't realize this set included daily data and I only needed the mean data for 1990, but from what it looks like "mean_1990 <- mean(MMAT)" did the trick!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  Both the raster and terra packages handle raster algebra gracefully using base operators like `mean()` (Robert wrote both packages so he may be able to give you more specifics if you're interested), so I think that line you add should be exactly what you need for either my approach or Robert's.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `terra` (the replacement of `raster`); perhaps like this:

```
library(terra)
r <- rast("air.mon.mean.v501.nc")

i <- grep("1990", time(r))
# or something like this but that is more tricky
#i <- which((time(r) > "1989-12-31") & (time(r) < "1990-12-31"))
i
# [1] 1081 1082 1083 1084 1085 1086 1087 1088 1089 1090 1091 1092

x <- r[[i]]
time(x)
# [1] "1990-01-01 UTC" "1990-02-01 UTC" "1990-03-01 UTC" "1990-04-01 UTC"
# [5] "1990-05-01 UTC" "1990-06-01 UTC" "1990-07-01 UTC" "1990-08-01 UTC"
# [9] "1990-09-01 UTC" "1990-10-01 UTC" "1990-11-01 UTC" "1990-12-01 UTC"
```

(Otherwise the same as Sean McKenzie's approach)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I went with Sean McKenzies approach which worked fine. Tho I later realized that might have to go with a whole other approach anyways, so your suggestions might come in helpful later on as well!